# Orient image to "face towards" another image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, random, uiimageview

Hi everyone I'm french so scuse me for my english.

I have an image (image1) in the middle of the screen that is static. Then I have another image (image2) that every time we open the application is at a random position. The image2 is a monkey with a head. What I want is that the head of the monkey is being oriented to the image1 every time we open the application. I think we must use rotation but I'm not sure. How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the angle between the center of image1 and image2 and then:

```
image2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

or if you want to animate it:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
image2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: how to calculate angle between the center of image1 and image2, here is my problem ?please

Comment: You'll need to learn or brush up on your trig, and just do the math. Trying googling "angle between x y coordinates". I know I'm not giving you the exact answer, but really, if you are doing this type of game-like iphone dev, it's worth knowing this. (IOS coordinates are in radians, not degrees)

Comment: I know but I don' have enough knolwedg about coding with trig to start. Is there a code for this or a tutorial ??

Comment: did you try googling "angle between x y coordinates" as I suggested?